# Angularjs Doc: confusing PUT invocation?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking at the [$resource Doc Page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and find some inconsistency in the way they invoke the $resource instance with update (PUT) method.

They first say that

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

But in their example "Creating a custom 'PUT' request", they invoke it like this:

```
// Now call update passing in the ID first then the object you are updating
Notes.update({ id:$id }, note);
```

So the note object here is neither a parameter nor a callback. Why is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their example, it follows the second bullet ("non-GET "class" actions) where `{id:$id}` sets the id in the URL and `note` gets serialized as the post data.